# How to best model a bi-directional association between two classes iny my python code

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, software-design

I have a numerical model that models some physical quantities. Now to analyse and administer the results of said model I am writing some python infrastructure code. The basic concepts I have are that of a model run (identified by its timestamp) and that of a quantity (identified by its name). As said each model run contains multiple quantities and a quantity can appear in multiple model runs.
My idea is thus to model the relationship between a model run and a variable by utilizing an additional class DataPoint.

The basic setup would look like this:

```py
class ModelRun:
    def __init__(self,timestamp):
        self.timestamp = timestamp
class Quantity:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
class DataPoint:
    def __init__(self,model_run,quantity):
        self.model_run = model_run
        self.quantity = quantity
```

Now like this the structure is of course not navigable. This could be solved by adding a list of datapoints to both the ModelRun as well as Quantity class like so:

```py
class ModelRun:
    def __init__(self,timestamp):
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.data_points = []
class Quantity:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.data_points = []
class DataPoint:
    def __init__(self,model_run,quantity,data):
        self.model_run = model_run
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.data = data
        quantity.data_points+=[self]
        model_run.data_points+=[self]
```

Is this a useful pattern? From my gut feeling it is a bit strange to modify instances of `Quantity` and `ModelRun` from within the `DataPoint.__init__` method. As my `ModelRun` and `Quantity` classes wil get more complex and be used in a lot of other parts of my code I am very much afraid to introduce some unnecessary mistakes at this stage.
Any suggestions appreaciated, thanks!

Comment: You could create a function to add datapoints in `Quantity` and `ModelRun` to avoid doing it in `__init__`

Comment: Just make `ModelRun.quantity` a list of `Quantity`, and `Quantity` seems like it could be something simple like `namedtuple` or maybe even just a `dict`.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy: I think I will stay with the approach to have a separate class to model the association. The Quantity class is quite more complex, I just wanted to break it down to the necessary parts for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

> From my gut feeling it is a bit strange to modify instances of Quantity and ModelRun from within the DataPoint.**init** method.

You could create classes to add the data_points, then you can reuse that method somewhere else in your code.

If you ever need to modify the logic in `add_data_point` you won't have to search all `quantity.data_points+=....` and `model_run.data_points+=....`

```
class ModelRun:
    def __init__(self, timestamp):
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.data_points = []

    def add_data_point(self, data_point):
        self.data_points.append(data_point)

class Quantity:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.data_points = []

    def add_data_point(self, data_point):
        self.data_points.append(data_point)

class DataPoint:
    def __init__(self, model_run, quantity, data):
        self.model_run = model_run
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.data = data

        model_run.add_data_point(self)
        quantity.add_data_point(self)
```

Comment: So generally you would see the layout as a useful pattern apart from your suggestion to incorporate the add_data_point methods in bot ModelRun and Quantity? Do you maybe have some more resources on this?